# How to resume an action when quitting with home button?

Tags: android, sip

I'm developping a SIP application. I have a little problem: when "reducing" the application with home button and i make a call to the phone, i have the coded ringing incoming call but the application doesn't shows. How to pops up all the application UI when having an incoming call ?
Thank you for your help.
EDIT:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,intent);
        dialog.répondre();
        }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have an Activity that is stopped and you want to pop it up when call arrives. Approach I would suggest:

- originally start that Activity with flag  FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
- override function onNewIntent() in that Activity and process incoming Intent depending on action code from Intent (you define them to distinguish reasons for popping up)
- when you want to move that Activity to foreground again, call startActivity() with some action code (you can to that from Service as well). If Activity is not started, it will be. If it is started, it will not be re-started but resumed and you will receive your Intent in onNewIntent() and your Activity will be moved to foreground.

**UPDATE:**

onNewIntent() handling example:

*\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app\SearchQueryResults.java*

Comment: @Zelimir: so in the "onreceive" function i have to write "startActivity()". But where have i put FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and onNewIntent() ? Have you please a link or can you edit your post with some help? Thank you very much.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP you put as flag in the Intent when you originally start the activity you want to wake-up. onNewIntent() is overriden in the Activity you want to wake up.

Comment: @Zelimir: in fact, when receiving a call, i don't have an intent, i'm calling a method in the other class(please see my first post), so how to put FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP there (if it's its right place). And then as i see in the "SearchQueryResults.java" link/code, i have to put onNewIntent() in the class "dialog" just before showing the confirmation alertdialog(confirm to answer a call or not). Right? And Thank you for your help.

Comment: IMO, when you receive a call you should send Intent (not call method directly) to that Activity. In onNewIntent() then you should call that method. This flag should be set when activity is first time started.

Comment: @Zelimir: Sorry but i think that i can't use startActivity() in a BroadcastReceiver. I verified it in my code and i have the waited error: The method startActivity(Class<dialog>) is undefined for the type IncomingCallReceiver.

Comment: No, you cannot startActivity() from the BroadcastReceiver. But, maybe you have some Service that is working in the background, and BroadcastReceiver attched to it?

Comment: @Zelimir: no i have not any service, in fact i tried to create one but i can not do it(i opened a topic here in stackoverflow but didn't have an answer (or a clear one)). So i have to create a service to make this feature working? okay i'll re-try making it :\

Comment: @androniennn: You should also take a look at the [`launchMode` attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) of the `activity` tag (member of androidManifest xml), to see what the `singleTop` means. Maybe you should give a try to `singleTask` as well, since it doesn't instantiates your class multiple times.

Comment: @rekaszeru: All the problem now is how to correctly create a service(i tried before but with no success). Plus, all the informations here are not ordered and i'm not knowing from where to begin :D :(

Comment: I just wanted to give you idea about one possible and IMO effective approach to the issue you have. I would suggest that you firstly mature Service creation.

Comment: @androniennn: As @Zelimir wrote, the service creation would be (if not the first, then) the next step, for which -if you're stuck- I suggest you create a new thread, and after describing your goal in detail, share your current status (code) in the implementation.